# border bottom not working print preview firefox css

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a table in my webpage. When i view the page in print preview in firefox the border bottom of the td doesn't display sometimes. In other browsers it's working fine. How to fix this?

Html:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Heading 1</td>
    <td>Heading 1</td>
    <td>Heading 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table td{ border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could speciify the media type in you CSS

```
<style>
    table td{ border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
    // Other CSS Styling here

    @media print {
        table td{ border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
    }

</style>
```

Comment: I would need to see your entire CSS and HTML because there is another issue here then. Something as simple as not declaring the correct doc type can cause browser abnormalities.

Comment: I just posted the whole css in this fiddle for your reference http://jsfiddle.net/VCwH8/.

Comment: there does not seem to be any big issues with your CSS so it could be a problem with the HTML. One thing i did notice in your CSS is `.block .formtblsec table.myTable td{ border:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black;padding:5px; }` You have double declared the value, this may cause an issue.